# fastest way to upload google photos (unlimited storage)

Tags: photos, google-photos

I have about 190gb of photos. Mostly high-quality jpegs (+/- 5mb per file).

They're residing on an HD on a Synology NAS. 
I can use an app called cloud sync and upload the photos to google drive. I turned on 'show google photos as folder in drive' but unfortunately all the files count up against the quota.

I don't care about the quality and use 'high quality' option @ Google Photos, which has unlimited storage.

**What would be the best way to upload all my photos?**

I would guess I need some binary/batch command that convert all my JPG's to a lower JPEG quality. I need to skip the JPEG's which are already low quality. Then I need to upload them.

Most convenient would be if I could do all of this from my NAS.

Perhaps even more convenient would be to upload the originals and somehow get Google to convert all of this + make use of the unlimited storage :)

*I'm on OSX, Mac high sierra.*

Comment: The only way to use the "high quality" option is to use the Google-provided utilities to do this, and it is best to send the highest-possible quality files into the Google process so that the output is still high-enough quality.

Comment: What happens if you select 1000 files and drop them into the Google Photos website?

Comment: @music2myear thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: @grawity that works! but it's kind of silly. I use my laptop to send the photo's from my synology  Perhaps should stick to this if there's no other option or first transfer to my laptop or smth. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are now [desktop applications](https://photos.google.com/apps) for macos and Windows that have specific support for Google Photos.  Just point them at the folders you use to store your photos and they'll sync them for you.